# How to configure where spark spills to disk?

Tags: apache-spark

I am not able to find this configuration anywhere in the official documentation. Say I decide to install spark, or use a spark docker image. I would like to configure where the "spill to disk" happens so that I may mount a volume that can accommodate that. Where does the default location of the spill to disk occur and how is it possible to change it?

Comment: https://www.kdnuggets.com/2020/07/apache-spark-cluster-docker.html

Comment: Added improved answer.

Answer (score 1):

> Cloud or bare metal worker nodes have spill location per node that is
> local file system, not HDFS. This is standardly handled, but not by
> you explicitly. A certain amount of the fs is used for spilling,
> shuffling and is local fs, the rest for HDFS. You can name a location
> or let HDFS handle that for local fs, or the fs can be an NFS, etc.

- For Docker, say, you need simulated HDFS or some linux-like fs for Spark intermediate processing. See https://www.kdnuggets.com/2020/07/apache-spark-cluster-docker.html an excellent guide.
- For Spark with YARN, use `yarn.nodemanager.local-dirs`. See https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/running-on-yarn.html
- For Spark Standalone, use `SPARK_LOCAL_DIRS`."Scratch" space in Spark, including map output files and RDDs that get stored on disk. This should be on a fast, local disk in your system. It can also be a comma-separated list of multiple directories on different disks.

Comment: Nice thanks so much for the information. Howcome for Docker you say you need a Simulated HDFS? Can't we run it without it? Or with some other DFS?

Comment: You need to read between the lines. See that link. See quoute: The components are connected using a localhost network and share data among each other via a shared mounted volume that simulates an HDFS. You cannot use Cassandra, say, for spillage. You can point to HDFS or something linux like DFS.